# Python MP3 ID3 Tag Editor

Tags: python, id3

Re-organizing a large MP3 library for my friend's MP3 Player, I have the need to name the Title ID3 tag the same as the file name, and doing this via Windows Properties takes forever, so I was wondering if anyone has an idea of how to make a Python script that does this to all MP3's in a directory in rapid succession. Or at least a link to a library installable on Windows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this:

- [ID3 Tagging in Python](http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/)
- [id3reader](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/id3reader.html)

Also [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html) uses MP3 ID3 tags as an example.

Don't forget about [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) - the Python Package Index.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a python script I wrote to do this https://gitlab.com/tomleo/id3_folder_rename

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import re
import glob
import subprocess

from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

path = os.getcwd()
fpath = u"%s/*.mp3" % path
files = glob.glob(fpath)

for fname in files:
    _track = EasyID3(fname)
    track_num = _track.get('tracknumber')[0]
    track_title = re.sub(r'/', '_', _track.get('title')[0])
    if '/' in track_num:
        track_num = track_num.split('/')[0]
    if len(track_num) == 1:
        track_num = "0%s" % track_num
    _valid_fname = u"%s/%s %s.mp3" % (path, track_num, track_title)
    if fname != _valid_fname:
        subprocess.call(["/bin/mv", fname, _valid_fname])
```

It uses the mutagen python library for parsing the ID3 info. You'll have to tweak the subprocess call it to make it work with windows, but this should give you an idea for how to do it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Digging this out because it is still a topic (17k views) and packages linked here are out-dated.

As of 10/2023 a quick search showed:

- [tinytag](https://pypi.org/project/tinytag/): Simple, in seemingly Pythonic way but can only read tags.
- [mutagen](https://pypi.org/project/mutagen/): More complex and can also write tags.

Possible duplicate: [ID3-mp3 editing in python - up-to-date package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279848/id3-mp3-editing-in-python-up-to-date-package)