# ID3-mp3 editing in python - up-to-date package?

Tags: python, mp3, id3

Edit: Trying to get these libraries to work in python 3.3 was clearly the wrong approach, and my problem now is entirely different so I'll just re-ask it in a new question.

I want to be able to edit ID3 tags of mp3 files with python commands, for example something like setAlbumName("folderPath\song.mp3", "albumname"). So far I've tried Mutagen, PyID3, pytagger, eyeD3, and they all seem to be outdated because the installation fails due to syntax errors. I tried to fix it in eyeD3, but I hit a dead end: http://i41.tinypic.com/o6zklv.png (second screenshot from after I had fixed all the prints and "except Error, e" and so on).

I tried the same with Mutagen, but I ran into a wall there as well when replacing "raise KeyError, key" with "raise KeyError as key" didn't work.

I didn't even know what to make of this one (pytagger): http://i41.tinypic.com/29fz7mh.png

It seems to suggest that there's something wrong with my python installation? Not getting into that.

So, would anyone like to point me to an ID3 package that works, or have a go at fixing an outdated one?

(Also, I tried both "python setup.py install" and "setup.py install" and it seemed to make no difference. I'm on windows 8.)

Edit: From the screenshot below, plus the source code (mutagen with python 2.7.5)

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
p = "E:\\Musik\\Aeon\\2005 Bleeding the False\\01 Cenobites - Copy.mp3"
audio = MP3(p)
audio["title"] = "An example"
audio.pprint()
audio.save()
```

_

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id3tag.py", line 5, in <module>
    audio.pprint()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mutagen\__init__.py", line 138, in pprint
    try: tags = self.tags.pprint()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mutagen\id3.py", line 190, in pprint
    frames = list(map(Frame.pprint, self.values()))
TypeError: unbound method pprint() must be called with Frame instance as first a
rgument (got str instance instead)
```

_

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
p = "E:\\Musik\\Aeon\\2005 Bleeding the False\\01 Cenobites - Copy.mp3"
audio = MP3(p)
audio["title"] = "An example"
audio.save()
```

_

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id3tag.py", line 7, in <module>
    audio.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mutagen\__init__.py", line 132, in save
    return self.tags.save(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mutagen\id3.py", line 370, in save
    framedata = [self.__save_frame(frame) for (key, frame) in frames]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mutagen\id3.py", line 461, in __save_frame

    framedata = frame._writeData()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_writeData'
```

Answer (score 1):

[mutagen](https://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) works great for me with Python 2.7.

examples:
https://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

audio = MP3("example.mp3")
audio["title"] = "An example"
audio.pprint()
audio.save()
```

p.s. please post code samples so people can help.. not links to screenshots.

p.p.s. it looks like you are trying to install Python2 libs into Python3.

Comment: How do you install it then? As I said, it doesn't work for me when I write "python setup.py install" or "setup.py install" as it seems to use outdated syntax such as print "stuff" rather than print("stuff"), and 'except Error, e' instead of 'except Error as e'.

Edit: nvm, saw that you use python 2.7.

Comment: Ok, I tried installing python 2.7, making it default and installing mutagen, and it's not working. (Linking to screenshot because I don't have enough characters to copy the traceback.) I get the first traceback with the example you gave, and the second one when I remove audio.pprint(): http://i41.tinypic.com/301ev5i.png

Comment: I told you, I don't have enough characters to copy the traceback (600 max). I also told you, my code is what you posted except I obviously replaced "example.mp3" with the path to an mp3 file on my computer, and the second error is from when I removed audio.pprint(). Would it help if I copied and reposted the code you posted, or what?

Comment: please learn how to use this site correctly.  I am done helping.

Comment: external links (including screenshots) rot off the web and make questions irrelevant over time.  this isn't a crowdsourced debugger for your own personal use.

Comment: Fine. I edited the first post to include source code and traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Mutagen also has an EasyID3 tool, which handles simple tasks like changing the file's title:

```
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
f = EasyID3("file.mp3")
f["title"] = u"Some title"
f.save()
```

Works like a charm. But it has very restricted functionality.
See more examples at http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial